Use openapi-generator to generate spring multitenant client
Openapi generator is a great tool when it comes to maintain services using REST API.
I have, however, following problem.
I am working in multitenant environment where I am developing service A that calls service B, but service B can be in fact B1, B2, B3. All B services share the same API contract but serve different data. Which service is selected, depends on the current thread cotnext in service A e.g. which user is logged in service A.
Example:

user1 logs in and runs operation on service A -> service B1 is called.
user2 logs in -> service B2
user7 -> B3
...
When I generate client using openapi-generator I can create a spring bean like:

@Bean
ServiceBApi serviceBApi(RestTemaplte restTemaplte){
   ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient(restTemplate);
   apiClient.setBasePath(baseUrl);   // base path changes on each request
   return new ServiceBApi(apiClient);
}

The problem is that basePath changes on each request so it cannot be set on bean creation, or new ServiceBApi instance needs to be created for each request.
Do you know any openapi-generator feature to reuse ServiceBApi bean and pass basePath on API call?
Or may some spring feature to do that to avoid object creation on each call?
I know that one of options could be defining custom template for generating ServiceBApi class, but I would like to avoid it.
